# Surface integral over portion of cylinder

Tags: integration

Could anyone point out my error, I disagree with a text books answer:

**Question:**

Evaluate $\int_s\boldsymbol F . d\boldsymbol S$ where $\boldsymbol F$ is the vector field $x^2 \boldsymbol i + 2z \boldsymbol j-y \boldsymbol k$ over the curved surface S defined by $x^2+y^2=25$ and bounded by z = 0, z = 6 and $y \geq 3$

**My Answer:**

$\int_s\boldsymbol F . d\boldsymbol S$ = $\int_s\boldsymbol F . \hat{\boldsymbol n}\,dS$

where

$\hat{\boldsymbol n}=\frac{\nabla S}{\left| \nabla S\right|}=\frac{2x \boldsymbol i + 2y \boldsymbol  j}{\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2}}=\frac{1}{5}(x \boldsymbol  i + y \boldsymbol j)$

Now, working in cylindrical polar coordinates, we have r = 5, z varies from 0 to 6 and $\phi$ varies from $\tan ^{ - 1}(\frac{3}{4})$ to $\pi - \tan ^{ - 1}(\frac{3}{4})$

This leads me to the integral

$5\int_{\phi={\tan ^{ - 1}(\frac{3}{4})}}^{\pi - \tan ^{ - 1}(\frac{3}{4})}\int_{z=0}^6\,25\cos^{3} \phi + 2\,z\,sin\,\phi\,dz\,d \phi$

I put this into wolfram alpha to check before solving manually, and I get the answer 288.

**Book's Answer:**

-80

Thanks for any help,
Mitch

Comment: Sorry, my final integration should go z = 0 to 6. But this just makes the answer 288, still wrong.

Comment: You seem to have dropped the factor $\frac15$ in $\hat n$. Other than that, your calculation seems OK to me, and I don't see how to obtain $-80$. Note that the problem is ill-posed in that the sign of the normal vector hasn't been fixed, so the fact that the book's answer has the opposite sign isn't meaningful. If I were you, I'd check whether you get the book's answer if you use $x\ge3$ instead of $y\ge3$.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Gauss's Theorem, which relates the surface integral over some closed surface $S$ to a volume integral over the (bounding) volume $V$, namely $\iint_{(S)} {\bf F} \cdot dS = \iiint_{(V)} \nabla \cdot F \,dV$.

Your function, ${\bf F} = x^2 \boldsymbol i + 2z \boldsymbol j -y \boldsymbol k$, gives $\nabla \cdot F = \frac{\partial x^2}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial -y}{\partial z} = 2x$. So you have to calculate

$\iiint_{(V)} \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol F \,dV = \iiint_{(V)} 2x\,dV$.

The integral over $dz$ is trivial, and is $6$. The integral over $dx, dy$ is more complicated and is $\int_{y=3}^{y-5} dy \int_{x=-\sqrt{25-y^2}}^{x=+\sqrt{25-y^2}} \, 2 x dx$.

Comment: Hint: $\int 2x \, dx = [x^2]$